# Difference between "-bash" and "bash"

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have always been using Bash shell in my terminal (OSX El Capitan) but for some weeks now it states "-bash" and tells me there are 2 "bash-alike" processes as you can see on the image.

Would someone know what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From [Invoking Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash) in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> A *login* shell is one whose first character of argument zero is ‘-’, or one invoked with the --login option

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll dig through it